# Any suggestion IF I need to write an iPhone/iPad app to show HTML5 content?

Tags: iphone

Is there any reference about writing an application on iPad/iPhone to show HTML5 content ?

- Any reference book
- Sample source codes
- Which components should I use ?

Million Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/)

Answer (score 4):

There already is an app on the iPad and iPhone for showing HTML5 content: Safari.

If you want to show **specific** HTML5 content within an app, just use a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).